# React Native JS concern

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am new to `react-native` world. Following few tutorials, I found that it `react-native` app runs on javascript engine on mobile. I am following ios tutorial. So when I go to `localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle` it loads JS for the app. I know I can use `ngrok` to manipulate this URL.

I have multiple concerns with this:-

1. If I change the URL of js from something local to something remote, this would result in a completely new app and now I don't need to go through the App Store to upgrade my app version. Can this be a potential issue in the future?
2. Since anybody can open this JS in a browser which might have important information like client id and secret for the app, can this be an issue as well?

Comment: 1. I am not 100% sure. You can update indeed update hybrid app easier and if it is only a quick fix you don't need to go through apple store verification process. Apple can also delete your app and ban you if you don't follow guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I am not 100% sure. You can indeed update hybrid app easier and if it is only a quick fix you don't need to go through apple store verification process. Apple can also delete your app and ban you if you don't follow guidelines. Usually your js is local in production for instant app start time, and the network is used only for fresh data.
2. This is solved with an authentication mechanism.

Comment: Firstly thanks for reply. 1. Got my answer 2. Nevermind, got my answer :)

Comment: @MalharShah -- if you have your answer please write it up here and mark it as the answer.